# .htaccess redirection to folders and subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am having issues with htaccess redirections. Following is the issues I am having.

The root folder to which the main domain actually points has the following folder: "example"
example.com is actually internally linked to the path "root/example/" rather than "root/". This is done using the following htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ example/index.html [L]
```

The folder "exmaple" has the following subfolders: newexample, newexample_beta
If I go to the URL "example.com/newexample", the URL needs to be internally linked to "root/example/newexample". But the URL redirects me to "example.com/example/newexample/"
could you please let me know what needs to be done

Comment: You mean it's externally redirected to example.com/example/newexample/?

Comment: Yes, the link is externally redirected to example.com/example/newexample/. It needs to stay in example.com/newexample/